# Problem using newtx

Tags: fonts, mactex, newtxmath, newtx

I want to use newtx to get a times font and have MaxTeX installed.
However, when I put `\usepackage{newtx}`and `\usepackage{newtxmath}` at the top of my tex file I get the error

```
LaTeX Error: File `newtx.sty' not found.
```

Now, when I search for newtx in `/usr/local/texlive` I get a number of folders and files come up. However, if I search for `newt.sty` there are no results.

If you could suggest what the problem is here (I think it is installed, so I don't know why the style file cannot be found) and how to make it work I would be grateful. Happy to answer any questions that may help locate the problem.

Comment: It should be `\usepackage{newtxtext}`, not `\usepackage{newtx}`

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was that simple, the tutorial I read had just newtx as the command!?

Comment: The place of that tutorial is the waste basket. `;-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although the TeX Live/MiKTeX package corresponding to the NewTX fonts is called `newtx`, this is of no consequence on how you have to load the LaTeX package.

<sub>The unfortunate circumstance that we use the term ‘package’ with two different meanings sometimes leads to confusion. They're two distinct planes: TeX Live/MiKTeX package provide infrastructure that *can* contain LaTeX packages, sometimes several of them.</sub>

The correct call is

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

Better doing separate calls, because the latter package accepts options that are not valid for the former. However, if you need no special option for the latter package, you can also do

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.7 (the current version is 1.704) of the New TX font package, you may use simply

```
\usepackage{newtx}
```

to automatically load both `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. Moreover, nearly all options for either `newtxtext` or `newtxmath` can be passed instead to `newtx`.

For finer control with other fonts, you may still separately load `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

From the command line, type `texdoc newtx` to read the complete documentation. Note in particular the instructions on how to use the package with XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX) instead of pdflatex (if you so wish).